# Why does a series or dataframe column of integers containing NaN values have "float64" as data type?

Tags: pandas, csv, nan, dtype

Either by using pd.read_csv or by defining a series of integers, if it contains a NaN value, then the data type of that series or column becomes "float64", including the respective ".0" at the end of each numeric value.

The data type of a column read from a CSV file is one of the characteristics I use for my analysis. When the data in a column is either integer or NaN values, once the table is loaded with pandas.read_csv, the dtype function returns the data type of that column as "float64", while its values are integers.

Answer (score 0):

Pure integers cannot be NaN. What you want is the [nullable int type](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html).

In code this might look something like:

`df=pd.read_csv("file.csv",dtype={"col1":str,"col_with_nan":Int64})`

Note the capital "`I`" in `Int64`.

Comment: The bad thing about that is that you first have to load the file without knowing which data types correspond to each column without considering the NaN. Even using the parameter "keep_default_na = False", it returns the column as "object" datatype. Thanks very much!!

Comment: You could cast an already existing column with something like `df=df.astype({"col_with_nan":Int64})`